# PhpStorm can't recognize custom Laravel facades

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

As said it the title: PhpStorm can't recognize custom Laravel facades.

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Here you are : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: Check this: https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/15

Comment: Thank you @AlexvanVliet four your reply, I just installed ide helper and phpstorm start to recognize system facades, but still it can't see my custom facades. how do I fix it ?

Comment: Same way -- re-generate ide-helper file. Works fine here with few custom facades. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne I tried over and over `php artisan ide-helper:generate` but still not working on custom facades :/

Comment: Are your facades in a namespace ? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/issues/127 according to this it could be an issue if they are in the global namespace (\\).

Comment: @AlexvanVliet nope, they're under the "App\Facades" namespace.. I added facades in alias like barry's said.. but it didin't work to :/

Comment: Does generated ide helper file contains your facade class? If not -- try executing `composer dump-autoload` and then `php artisan package:discover` and then re-generate ide helper again (`php artisan ide-helper:generate && php artisan ide-helper:meta`). It definitely works. It has to be user specific issue or you are doing something wrong at some point (missing some step etc)... Don't forget to hit `File | Synchronize` in PhpStorm once done and allow 1-2 mins (or close and reopen project)

Comment: @LazyOne ohh that works ! thank you so much, you may wan to add this as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package that will create some helper files for IDE eyes only -- IDE will parse them as ordinary PHP files and will use for code analysis/completion.

If it still does not work for you... then you must be missing some step or doing something wrong at some point.

To be sure that you do not miss anything please do these steps:

- Open terminal in project root folder
- execute `composer dump-autoload`
- then `php artisan package:discover`
- then re-generate IDE helper files (`php artisan ide-helper:generate && php artisan ide-helper:meta`)

Depending on how IDE is configured, you may need to hit `File | Synchronize` in PhpStorm and allow around 1-2 mins (depends on your hardware etc) for it to pickup the changes in generated IDE helper file. Alternatively -- close and open project again.

Answer (score 3):

If the ide-helper package actually let's you down, you can use the `@mixin` PhpDocBlock attribute to link your facade to the class that you are accessing through the facade.

- [Auto-Completion for Laravel Facades](https://thomasventurini.com/auto-completion-for-laravel-facades)

Comment: The link is no longer available, but this solution worked for me. To be more specific, you need to specify the `@mixin` attribute in a PHPDoc comment in the facade definition.